# Where is the Swift CocoaTouch documentation?

Tags: cocoa, swift

I imagine the Swift language has gotten the attention of a boatload of iOS programmers - many of whom never wrote a single line of Objective-C in their life.

For example I have dozens of apps on the app store, written in Titanium.

In the Titanium world every property and event available is documented, for example like this for UILabel:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Label

Is there an Apple equivalent?  I read the Apple iBook on Swift - it discusses the core language, it doesn't list out the methods available in the Cocoa touch framework, and leaves it to the programmer to intuitively guess based on their Objective-C experience.

Is that a fair assessment, that that you have to learn Objective-C first and then use that as a bridge language to Swift - or is Swift intended to be stand-alone?  If so, where is the documentation of Cocoa Touch, in swift?

Comment: I just use the documentation included when I installed Xcode6. Is there something else you were looking for?

Comment: If I search stack overflow, I can find an example of someone who has given an example of UILabel:          var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
        label.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.text = "I am a test label" --- but this begs the question, what are the rest of the methods?  I want to look through all the options available.

Comment: p.s. coming from Titanium world, I didn't even know about the xCode 6 documentation.  Reading through other stack overflow threads - people mentioned the Swift iBook - which I've already read.  I am now looking through the Documentation and API reference of xCode - see if it has what I need.  thanks

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is included in Xcode6 (or can be downloaded). You can currently access it by going to `Window -> Documentation and API Reference`. (or by pressing `shift`, `command` & `0`)

You will then have full access to search and find resources here. You can also  `option` click on something in Xcode to pull up the docs for that specific thing.

As you will see it shows you the declarations for Obj-C and Swift together. This technically isn't Swift documentation (it is the iOS8 library documentation) but it should be similar to what you were looking for.

Note: this post originally included screen shots but I removed them as developers are [not supposed to post screen shots](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/apple-lifted-beta-nda/) of pre-released software.

Comment: This is pre-release information and probably shouldn't be discussed here.

Answer (score 0):

The Cocoa Touch APIs and frameworks are the same between Swift and Objective-C. There are only [minor syntax differences](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/using-swift-cocoa-objective/id888894773?mt=11) used when you call the APIs. The framework documentation is currently pre-release, so if you aren't a registered developer then you can't see it yet.